# What happens when a server closes the connection and the client sends some data at the same time?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming

I have a server written in `C` that closes the connection if the connection is sitting idle for a specific time. I have an issue (that rarely happens). Read is failing on the client side and it says `Connection broken`. I suspect the server is closing the connection and the client is sending some data at the same time.

Consider the following scenario (A is server, B is the client)

1. `B` initiates the connection and the connection between `A` and `B` is established.
2. `B` is sitting idle and the idle timeout is reached.
3. `A` initiates the close
4. Before `B` receives the `FIN` from `A`, it starts sending request to `A`
5. After `B` sends the request, it will read the response

Since `A` has already closed the connection, `B` is not able to read.

My questions are

1. Is this a possible situation ?
2. How to handle idle timeout for clients?
3. How to close the connection between `A` and `B` properly (avoid `B` sending request during the process). In short, how to close the connection atomically?

Comment: You shouldn't use code formatting for emphasis, code formatting is used for code. Instead use bold or italics as you would do when writing a letter in MS Word.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. If the timeout is 5 seconds, the client should never allow more than one second between messages. If the client has nothing to send, and one second has elapsed, then it should just send a keep alive message, i.e. a message with no content. Adjust the timeout value as desired, but the timeout should be generous compared to the keep alive rate. 3. Before closing the connection (due to a timeout), the server should send a "timeout detected" message to the client.

Comment: I can't agree with all the suggestions for the server to send a timeout message. At this point the server has to assume the connection is broken, and it may *be* broken, and in any case the timeout message may never arrive at the cllient, or the client may not respond to it correctly: and if the server *then* closes the connection the client can *still* get `broken pipe`. You just have to put up with the `broken pipe` message. All the timeout message and response do is add further oppourtunities for `broken pipe` to occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to close the connection between A and B properly (avoid B sending request during the process).

- Server detects timeout
- Server sends *timeout detection* message to the Client
- Server waits for a reply (if timeout, assume Client dead)
- if Client receives a *timeout detection* from the Server, it replies with *ACK* (or something like that)
- if Server receives an *ACK* from the Client, then 'gracefully' closes the connection
- from now on, neither the Server nor the Client should send/receive any messages (after sending the *ACK*, do not immediately close the connection from the client side, do linger for the agreed timeout - see setsockopt: SO_LINGER)

On top of that, like the other answers suggested, the Client should send a *heartbeat* if idle (to avoid timeout detections).

Comment: This is also a fine solution, but does not cover the situation when the connection is disrupted for other reasons. The client still needs to handle a send error.

Comment: @thebusybee I don't think that this is the issue here. Of course, you're right that a transmission error has to be proper handled, but as far as i understood the OP, the problem arises not when an error occurs, but on normal circumstances, which btw. can ans will happen. I thought a proper handshake would be the solution.

Comment: Alll this is just replicating what TCP/IP already does. And what happens if the server times out reading the timout response from the client? There is no advantage.

Comment: @user207421 From the manpage of `send`: _No indication of failure to deliver is implicit in a send(). Locally detected errors are indicated by a return value of -1._ How does this help with the question of the OP? The OP is looking for that guarantee.

Comment: The OP *can't* have that guarantee, for precisely the reason you stated. Your timeout message isn't guaranteed to be delivered any more than anything else, and the server can't tell whether it was delivered or not.

Comment: @user207421 Ok, rfc793 (section 3.5) and rfc1122 (section 4.2.2.13) describes how a close has to take place. And you're right, it's basically reimplementing the tcp protocol. If the OP sets a timeout via SO_TIMEOUT, then my suggestion is indeed a bad choice, because, while tcp handles the 'close', we want to transmit additional messages. I should have noticed, that if the OP wants 'full' control on whats happening, then it could be (re-) implemented in the application layer (inclusive timeout, quasi connection and not socket based).

Comment: @user207421 The application layer approach has one advantage, that if a (connection) timeout occurs, the Client could reply to keep the connection open, quasi "hey, sorry server, i was a bit busy and didn't mean to keep you waiting, please, let us continue".

Answer (score 3):

By my only little more than rudimentary network experience... and assuming that you are talking about a connection-oriented connection like TCP/IP in contrary to UDP/IP that is connection-less.

1. Yes, of course. You cannot avoid it.
2. There are multiple ways to do it, but all of them include: Send something from the client before the server's timeout elapses. If the client has no data to send, let it send something like a "life sign". This could be an empty data message, it all depends on your application protocol. Or make the timeout as long as necessary, including some margin. Some protocol timeout only after 3 times of allowed idle time.
3. You cannot close the connection atomically, because client and server are separated. Each packet on the network needs some time to be transmitted, and both can start sending at the very same moment, the server its closing message, and the client a new data message. There is nothing that you can do about this.

   You need to make the client handle this situation properly. For example, it can accept such a broken connection and interpret it as closed. You should have already some reaction, if the server closes the connection while the client is idle.